# "Coercivity" of a bilinear form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bilinear-form

Let $D$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the following bilinear form:

$$
B
\bigg [
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\
  v
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
  U \\
  V
\end{pmatrix}
\bigg ]
=
\int_{\mathcal{D}}
(u_{x_2} - v_{x_1})
(U_{x_2} - V_{x_1})
+
(u_{x_1} + v_{x_2})
(U_{x_1} + V_{x_2})
dx
$$

where $u,v, U,V \in H^1(\mathcal{D})$.
I am interested in answering the question whether there exist constants $\gamma, C > 0$ such that:

$$
B
\bigg [
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\
  v
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\
  v
\end{pmatrix}
\bigg ]
+ 
\gamma ( ||u||_{L^2(\mathcal{D})} + ||v||_{L^2(\mathcal{D})} )
\geq 
C ( ||u||_{H^1(\mathcal{D})} + ||v||_{H^1(\mathcal{D})} )
$$

for each $u,v \in H^1(\mathcal{D})$. Can somone help me how to proceed? I am a bit stuck here.

**Edit:** Consider the system for PDE:

$$
\begin{cases}
- \Delta u + \gamma u = f, - \Delta v + \gamma v = g & \text{in } \mathcal{D} \\
u_{x_2} = v_{x_1}, u_{x_1} = - v_{x_2}, & \text{on } \partial \mathcal{D}
\end{cases}
$$

for $f,g \in L^2(\mathcal{D})$ and $u,v \in H^1(\mathcal{D})$. Then one can show (as I already have) that the weak formulation of this BVP is:

$$
B
\bigg [
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\
  v
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
  U \\
  V
\end{pmatrix}
\bigg ]
=
\int_{\mathcal{D}} fU + gV dx.
$$

where $u,v, U,V \in H^1(\mathcal{D})$.